# is it possible to stop the user from clicking a different application other than my tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to use `tkinter` to stop a user from clicking off my application. In other words making my program the top level program at all times?

Comment: I hope your operating system prevents one application from blocking access to all others :(

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge its only a small password entry program which will release focus and close when correct password is entered

Comment: What you're trying to do is quite innocent, but I don't think any mainstream preemtive multitasking OS (Linux, Windows, OsX) will allow it. Search for 'system modal dialog'. It was removed already from Win32.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge ill let you know if it works or not when i get there

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is called a "grab". Tkinter supports grabs with several methods.

To do what you want requires a global grab, which effectively freezes your entire display except for your specific window. This is very dangerous since you can easily lock yourself out of your own computer if you have a bug in your code.

For more information, read about grab_set and other grab commands here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_set-method

Comment: Hi Bryan the all mighty `tkinter` master if i am understanding right i am supposed to use `grab_set_global()` at the beginning anf then when program ends call `grab_release`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: yes.

Comment: because thats what i tried but it still allows me to click on other open programs, it just stops them from maximising the window, could it be like jacques says in the comments that windows blocks it?